# How to retrieve the full path of file during file upload in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a WEB application where few clients have ability to upload the file. Actual files are mapped to server drive where few users would have access to.

Is it possible to get the full path of the file which is mapped to server?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpServerUtility.MapPath` returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path on the Web server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just to clearly explain a scenario: File path being selected by such user will not be the same where my web application is deployed. There is another directory where file resides. That directory is mapped to other machines from where users would upload files on server. Since the file already exist on server, I do not want to keep duplicate copies of the same file at two places. Instead, I would like to store the file path only.

Comment: @SachinGaur sorry, I dont andustend your requirements... could you improve your question with more details and examples